# Can't define alerts on some of the metrics defined by a plugin - edit button missing

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I'm using the RabbitMQ plugin for New Relic from Pivotal (https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/351496/plugins/directory/95). I'm trying to figure out how I can control which metrics I can use for alerts. I've looked at the source code for the agent and it reports a number of metrics but the plugin interface only allows me to define alerts on the first 3.

After searching for a solution I found this: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/plugin-dev/creating-summary-metrics-for-plugins

Unfortunately, the RabbitMQ plugin doesn't seem to have the "Edit" button that these instructions refer to.

So, is this something anybody has seen before? Can something be done about it?

Answer (score 0):

Currently New Relic doesn't support alerting on arbitrary metrics. You can alert on Apdex, Error Rate and Server Monitor metrics (CPU, RAM, Disk, Network) as well as downtime events detected by Availability Monitoring. You might consider filing a ticket with support.newrelic.com to make a formal feature request.

Comment: Well, OK, but this is a plugin I'm talking about. From looking at the code (https://github.com/gopivotal/newrelic_pivotal_agent/blob/master/plugins/pivotal_rabbitmq_plugin/pivotal_rabbitmq_plugin.rb) I see that it's reporting 11 metrics but in the New Relic web UI I can only create an alert on three of these metrics (the top three) and for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to specify which three metrics can be used as "alert metrics".

Comment: It is possible to alert on summary metrics for New Relic Platform Plugins, but these are specified by the plugin author.  It seems that you were looking at the documentation for plugin authors.  That's why the Edit button isn't available.